# PdfConcatenate (smart) in iText 7

Tags: java, itext, itext7

In iText v5 there was the option to make 'smart' concatenation of PDF documents:

```
public PdfConcatenate(OutputStream os, boolean smart) throws DocumentException
```

> Creates an instance of the concatenation class.
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
> os - the OutputStream for the PDF document
> smart - do we want PdfCopy to detect redundant content?
> ```

The initialization I was doing would be something like:

```
PdfConcatenate concatenatedPdf = new PdfConcatenate(outputStream, true);
```

In iText 7 I read we should use the copyPages function. Something like:

```
[...]
PdfDocument concatenatedPdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
PdfDocument docToAdd = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);
docToAdd.copyPagesTo(1, docToAdd.getNumberOfPages(), concatenatedPdf);
```

I'm migrating a logic to merge documents from iText v5 to v7. For a sample test in v5 with PdfConcatenate and the flag 'smart' the result PDF is 177 KB, in v7 is 763 KB. Is there a way to detect this redundant content in iText v7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `iText7` provides a convenient class called `PdfMerger` for merging PDFs.

Here is a sample how to use it:

```
PdfDocument sourceDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(filename));

PdfMerger resultDocument = new PdfMerger(new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(resultFile)));
resultDocument.merge(sourceDocument, fromPage, toPage);
resultDocument.close();
sourceDocument.close();
```

Of course in the example only one set of pages from source document is added to the resultant document but you can call `merge` function as many times as you like.

Now when you want the resultant file to be as small in terms of file size as possible, you need to specify some settings for the destination `PdfDocument` that you feed to the `PdfMerger`.

First of all, you can tweak the compression level for streams to use more CPU and time but compress better:

```
PdfMerger resultDocument = new PdfMerger(new PdfDocument(
            new PdfWriter(resultFile, new WriterProperties().setCompressionLevel(CompressionConstants.BEST_COMPRESSION))));
```

To compress even better you can use full compression. That would not only better compress streams (content of the page, images, fonts), but also would compress PDF objects that usually consume many bits in the out file size. This can be done like this:

```
PdfMerger resultDocument = new PdfMerger(new PdfDocument(
            new PdfWriter(resultFile, new WriterProperties().setFullCompressionMode(true))));
```

In case source documents have same objects by default you might have some duplication. So-called "Smart Mode" provides a possibility to avoid such duplication and optimize the file size for cases when there are many duplicating objects. This would be the closes analogue to the "smart" flag you refer to in your iText 5 code. You can enable smart mode in iText 7 in the following way:

```
PdfMerger resultDocument = new PdfMerger(new PdfDocument(
            new PdfWriter(resultFile, new WriterProperties().useSmartMode())));
```